# How to play HLS on Android < 3.0?

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming

I want to play [an HLS stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) on Android < 3.0. I can not use 3rd party library. I can not port FFMPEG. Is it possible to change the stream container and play the stream using only java code? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a high level media framework, check out [vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/).

Comment: @yorkw, thanks for response. I want to implement http-live-streaming myself, no need for [vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/).

Comment: It's possible, but an extremely large amount of work.